# How do you create a border around the outside of a selection with GIMP?

Tags: gimp

How do you create a border around the **outside** of a selection using GIMP?

When I create a border using the Selection tool and the `Edit -> Stroke Selection...` menu option, the border is centered on the selection.

For example, if use `Stroke selection...` to draw around the perimeter of the selection a line that is 8 pixels wide, 4 of those pixels will be inside selection and 4 will be outside the selection.

How do you create a border that only has pixels on the outside of the selection?

Answer (score 0):

Use stroke selection like you normally do, but afterwards, clear the selection using `Edit->Clear`.

This is best done using a new layer whose express purpose is adding a border, as you'll be deleting everything inside the selection.